# slack-ruby-client - RealTime on_complete': not_allowed_token_type (Slack::Web::Api::Errors::NotAllowedTokenType)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, slack

I want to implement Socketmode on Slack and communicate that, with my ruby project which uses this gem [slack-ruby-client](https://github.com/slack-ruby/slack-ruby-client).

I did exactly what the [document](https://github.com/slack-ruby/slack-ruby-client#realtime-client) says, but I got this error:
`on_complete': not_allowed_token_type (Slack::Web::Api::Errors::NotAllowedTokenType)` .

*NOTE*:

1. according to the [Slack document](https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/socket#token)
   for real-time(socket-mode) token, we must use an **App-level** token, but I see `on_complete': not_allowed_token_type (Slack::Web::Api::Errors::NotAllowedTokenType)` error.
2. when changing the type of token from **App-level** to **User-level**, the error change to `on_complete': missing_scope (Slack::Web::Api::Errors::MissingScope)`

my simplified code is:

```html
Slack::Web::Client.configure do |config|
  config.token = ENV['SLACK_API_TOKEN_USER']
end

Slack::RealTime::Client.configure do |conf|
  conf.token = ENV['SLACK_API_TOKEN_APP']
end

module Slack
  client = Slack::RealTime::Client.new
  client.start!
end
```

also, I tried to create a legacy Bot and use that token. unexpectedly everything went fine !!!! but I don't want use the legacy one.

> Connect a bot to the Slack Real Time Messaging API. Please note,
> this is a legacy custom integration - an outdated way for teams to
> integrate with Slack. These integrations lack newer features and they
> will be deprecated and possibly removed in the future. We do not
> recommend their use. Instead, we suggest that you check out their
> replacement: Slack apps

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the scope to that token. I don't know exactly which scope is needed for that feature. Each token is associated with one or several scopes to configure what the token can and can't do.

Comment: I tried all scopes but it doesn't work